# Delete Entry from DGV and SQLite DB (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

In my program I have a dgv on one form. When I delete an entry from the dgv, I would also like to delete the entry from the SQLite database, so that it doesn't re-appear.

I have an 'id' column (PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT), so that each item is unique.

What I'm having trouble doing is accessing the 'id' with the row deleted.

Here is some of the code:

```
DialogResult deleteitem = MessageBox.Show("Delete the selected item?", "Delete Item", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
if (deleteitem == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    if (!this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
          SetConnection();
          sqlconnection.Open();

          this.dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.rowIndex);

          sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=???", sqlconnection);
          sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the ID in the row somewhere? If so, extract it's value before removing the row.

Comment: No, the dgv is only displaying 'Item' and 'Quantity'.

Comment: Use the `.DataBoundItem` property of the row to access its underlying data record.

Comment: If you add the Id as a [hidden column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383893%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) then you can retrieve it in order to delete the item

Comment: How would I retrieve the 'id' number? My current code is: `int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value);`, but variable id, isn't being recognized in this statement: `sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id= " + id + "", sqlconnection);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you will want to build your SQLLiteCommand before your remove the row from you grid.  You can use either approach suggested in the comments above.  You can access the DataBoundItem like so:

```
MyRowDataType dataRow = (MyRowDataType)this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex].DataBoundItem;
```

then you can delete this way (But you need to know the type of your underlying data and change the MyRowDataType to your data's type):

```
sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=" + dataRow.ID, sqlconnection);
```

OR you can add the ID column to your DataGridView as a hidden column and access the value this way:

```
sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=" + this.dataGridView.Rows[this.rowIndex].Cells["IDColumnName"].Value, sqlconnection);
```

Comment: I've added an ID column. And I used the line of code you suggested, but I get an error when I attempt to delete an item: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Never mind. I had that code running after deleting the item lol It's working now. Thank you